# Seemingly random slow SSD disk speed

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have problems with slow disks that I can't solve.

I have Windows installed on a Kingston Fury Renegade M.2. I have a new Samsung 870 QVO and an old Samsung 840 Pro.

When I first installed the new Samsung disk, I noticed it was very slow. The old Samsung disk was as fast as i expected it to be. I switched their cables and then the speeds switched - the new disk was fast and the old was slow.

I've tried different SATA-ports and different cables. I've tried connecting just one of them and finally thought that I figured out it was a power cable issue. I then actually managed to use both drives with good benchmark speeds. I had the drives outside the computer, and when I put them inside and connected them the same way, one of them was slow again. My best guess is that it goes up and down and sometimes when I run the benchmark it just happens to be fast.

I don't now why this happens or how to solve it.

This is three benchmarks from the last 15 minutes:

[image]